# How to order Subcategory list by ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this part of code:

```
<?php
    $cat_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $i = $cat_object->term_id;

    while (true) {
        $cat = get_category($i);
        if ($cat->category_parent) {
            $i = $cat->category_parent;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $parentcat = $i;
    if (is_category(array(8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))) {
        wp_list_categories("depth=2&child_of=" . $parentcat . "&title_li=");
    } else {
        wp_list_categories("depth=1&child_of=" . $parentcat . "&title_li=");
    }

?>
```

It shows me my Categorys and Subcategorys if they are present. Now I need to order the list of subcategorys are shown.

What I see:

- Cat1
- Cat2
- Cat3

  - cat1
  - cat6
  - cat5
  - cat3
- Cat4

But I need to order my Subcategories by ID.

Comment: Have you try using `orderby=ID`?

Comment: yes, it changes the whole list of categoris. But I need to change only Subcategories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) they have some arguments that will help you. Namely the `order` and `orderby` arguments. Try this:

```
<?php
    $cat_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $i = $cat_object->term_id;

    while (true) {
        $cat = get_category($i);
        if ($cat->category_parent) {
            $i = $cat->category_parent;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $parentcat = $i;
    if (is_category(array(8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))) {
        wp_list_categories("depth=2&child_of=$parentcat&orderby=name&order=DESC");
    } else {
        wp_list_categories("depth=1&child_of=$parentcat");
    }

?>
```

I refactored your URL a little. I removed the `title_li` argument since you weren't passing a parameter. Also, since you were using double quotes `"` to wrap your string, you can use the variable directly in the string without having to concatenate.

Anyway, you will notice the addition to the end of the string to organize the categories alphabetically. You can change this to be a number of different things, but you can find those on the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).

**Update based on comments**

Ordering just the sub-categories cannot be achieved simply with the `wp_list_categories()` function alone. You either need to define a [custom walker](http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html) to sort just the child categories or you could try a plugin to change how you sort categories.

This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/order-categories/) is a little outdated, but it still works! Make sure you remove the `order` and `orderby` arguments in the string.

Comment: Same here, this kind of order is changing the whole list, but I only need to order subcategories.

Comment: You have two lists that are being rendered. I am assuming that the first list in your code is subcategories and the second is parent categories (this assumption is based on the depth parameters). If that is the case, simply remove the `order` and `orderby` arguments from the string. Answer updated.

Comment: It's the same list both times, if im on category 8 it shows me subcategories, if not - no. If im changing order or orderby it changes the whole list. And I want to change only subcategories if im on category 8.. I hope you can understand it, sorry for my bad english by the way.

Comment: I see what you are doing. This cannot be achieved simply with the `wp_list_categories` function. You either need to define a custom walker to sort just the child categories or you could try a plugin to change how you sort categories. This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/order-categories/) is a little outdated, but it still works! Make sure you remove the `order` and `orderby` arguments in the string. I will update the answer with this information.